# leave instruction returns a seg fault

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, 32-bit

I have a routine that perform calls to a routine where a value into `ebp` register is expected.I change it several times in the routine.So,I can't do: `mov ebp,esp` in the top of code.I tried by saving the `esp` address in another register and before `leave` instruction put such address into `ebp` but I still get a segmentaion fault.

How to fix this?

the code is very huge(to post here,but I can post if needed),but the idea is something like this:

```
;a lot of arguments are passed in stack
foo:
xor ebx,ebx
mov ecx,esp
loop0:
sub edx,1
jz end
;etc
mov eax,[esp+ebx]
mov ebp,eax
call routinex
;etc..
;...
mov ebp,edx
call printx
add ebx,4
jmp loop0
end:
mov ebp,ecx
leave
ret
```

I hope this code is enough for you get the idea..
I also like an explanation.

Comment: It seems you've already noticed the problem: "I change [the value of EBP] several times in the routine". Don't do that.

Comment: @SecurityMatt: But I restore it in `end` label. Is not enough? leave from instruction with `esp` address at `ebp`?

Comment: Also,it's a register used by routine that I'm calling,how will I set it without modify `ebp` value?

Comment: Not really. EBP is needed for stack unwinding if you hit an exception. Also using ECX as your stack pointer is a bad idea - since ECX is a volatile register over any function call. If you must use an alternative register, use one like EDI or ESI.

Comment: @SecurityMatt:I know,but it's because ECX is the free register that I can use,the others registers are input to this routine,and I can't modify until `loop0` end.But I will try to reorganize the paramaters to use `esi`(edi is busy) instead of `ecx`. Thanks. :) I new to assebmly too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `leave` does is this:

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

If you want to use it and have it work, you should write something like

```
push ebp
mov ebp, ecx
leave
```

At the end of your function. Of course, you could just dispense with using `leave` altogether if you do:

```
mov esp, ecx
ret
```

since you are using `ecx` as your frame pointer.

Comment: I get working at top:`push ebp
 mov esi,esp` and at end: ` mov esp,esi
 mov ebp,esp
 leave
 ret` give no seg fault. Is this implementation right?

Comment: Another dump question: Why do I need to put `ebp` address in stack if I don't pop it from there?or am I wrong?